# Is there something I can add to my ESP8266 script to track how much data it uses on WiFi?

Tags: esp8266

I want to set it up on a mobile hotspot but I'd like to get an idea of how much data my sketch uses first.

Comment: keep a running tally of the length of data being sent ... you could keep track of received data also

Comment: But I don't know the size of the data I am sending, it's just two JSON objects.